# AWS Dotnet Serverless function template wont load appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I created a new AWS Serverless function and started to try and get configuration from appsettings.json file but I cannot get it to load.

First, there was not an appsettings.json file there, so I copied one in from another project.

here is the appsettings.json file contents

```
    "MyConfig": {
        "AwsRegion": "us-east-2",
        "S3CodeBucket": "mydata-bucket"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "db": "***"
    }
}
```

There is some code to uncomment in the Startup.cs file, so I uncommented, and then added the section to get my custom section and I get a null result

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //// Example of creating the IConfiguration object and
    //// adding it to the dependency injection container.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false);

    var my_config = builder.Build().GetSection(nameof(MyConfig)).Get<MyConfig>();

    if (my_config != null )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(my_config.AwsRegion);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to thinking, this is because the lambda function is just a assembly DLL that gets ran either by the Mock Lambda Testing tool if local or the Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport executable on AWS. So, in order to load a config file from an assembly dll you have to do the following:

```
var assemblyLoc = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLoc);
var configFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "appsettings.json");

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile(configFilePath)
    //.AddSystemsManager("/AppPrefix", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240))
    .Build();
```

Alternatively, I can uncomment the AddSystemManager line and get settings from Systems Manager Parameter store, which is a good option, but it will cost money each time you access it.